# Events/commands not working

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord

When I check for an event like `on_message(message)`, every command stops working

If I remove the event, everything is back to normal.

With this code, commands are not working.

```
@bot.event
async def on_ready():
   print("Connected.")    

@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
   print("test")

@bot.command(pass_context=True)
async def hello(ctx):
   print("test")
```

While removing the event section, the command works normally.

Comment: You forgot the underscore while defining on_message.

Comment: I just wrote a similar piece of code, anyway it didn't solve my problem

Answer (score 0):

As written [here](http://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/faq.html#why-does-on-message-make-my-commands-stop-working), you need to explicitly invoke the command when you override on_message

```
@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    # do some extra stuff here

    await bot.process_commands(message)
```